# ASP.NET MVC - Automatically deserialise JSON Fetch POST

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, fetch-api

I am using the [github/fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) to post some data back to the server.

```
fetch('./PerformSearch', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-type' : 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        terms: this.refs.termsFilter.getSelections(),
        details: this.refs.detailsFilter.getSelections(),
        dateRange: {
            from: new Date(),
            til: new Date()
        }
    })
})
```

but the controller is not automatically deserialising the body of the request to the data object in the argument like it would do from form variables. If I do this using XmlHttpRequest though, it works..

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        ...
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

The function receiving the request in the controller is pretty simple at the moment - it doesn't do anything, I am just trying to get it to deseralise the json body to the data object right now using the following:

```
public JsonResult PerformSearch(SearchModel.SearchSelections data)
{
    //data has not been serialised
    Stream req = Request.InputStream;
    string body = new IO.StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd;

    Console.WriteLine(body); // writes a json string
}
```

So yes, I could deserialise this myself inside the function using the json library, but I would rather find a way to have the controller do it for me.

UPDATE:

Here is the .net object I am trying to deseralise to:

```
class SearchModel
{
    public class SearchSelections
    {
        public SearchTermList terms { get; set; }
        public SearchDetailsList details { get; set; }
        public DateRange dateRange { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchTermList
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> exams { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> areas { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> classes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> tokens { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchDetailsList
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> studyTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> species { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> strains { get; set; }
    }

    public class DateRange
    {
        public System.DateTime @from { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime til { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your SearchModel.SearchSelections model correspond JSON model that you transfer to server?

Comment: yeah, i can add them both in the question if you like?

Comment: yes, please add it

Comment: Ok will have to post it in the morning, I don't have that laptop with me right now.

Comment: Don't striglify the body request. Pass the json

Comment: Check the "Network" tab of a browser and see it there are any differences between requests send by fetch() and XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: @DennisNerush it doesn't even get to the server if I remove `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Azargoth good shout, the `Content-type` that was getting sent with `fetch` was `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.. the property on fetch was `headers` not `header` *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake:

```
header: {'Content-type' : 'application/json'}
```

should have been `headers`:

```
headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json'}
```